# Creating Tabhost and Adding specs from AsyncTask in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-tabhost

I am trying to create a tabbar and specs in it , but the thing is I need to do it in an asycn task so its without TabActivity. After running this code below I only see my main layout. And in the end what Im trying to do is, I wanna show a progress bar to the user which say the necessary files are getting copied just for the first time once application is installed, in the mean time copy files then create tabHost and add specs. Without an asyncTask it works quite good but for the first time application runs the screen gets locked for 20 or 30 seconds till the copying process get done. Any idea ? Thanks in advance.

```
public class AsyncTest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

Context context;
DataBaseJSONFunctions json;

TabHost tabHost;

TabWidget tabWidget;

Resources res;

TabHost.TabSpec sp;

Intent intent;

ProgressDialog dialog;

Activity ac;

public AsyncTest(Context context, TabHost tabHost, TabHost.TabSpec sp, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.context = context;
    json = new DataBaseJSONFunctions(context);
    this.tabHost = tabHost;
    tabWidget = tabHost.getTabWidget();
    this.sp = sp;
    ac = (Activity) context;
    res = context.getResources();

    LocalActivityManager mlam = new LocalActivityManager(ac, false);
    mlam.dispatchCreate(savedInstanceState);
    tabHost.setup(mlam );

}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    initializeAll();
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

    dialog.dismiss();

    // to go through to the another activity in the tab I need to initialize an intent.
    // and I need to set the Tab bar and it's icon.
    intent = new Intent().setClass(ac, Activities.class);
    sp = tabHost.newTabSpec("activities").setIndicator("activities",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_activities_selector)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(sp);

    // doing the same things for Songs Activity.
    intent = new Intent().setClass(ac, Promotions.class);
    sp = tabHost.newTabSpec("promotions").setIndicator("promotions",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_promotions_selector)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(sp);


    // doing the same things for another Activity.
    intent = new Intent().setClass(ac,Menu.class);
    sp = tabHost.newTabSpec("menu").setIndicator("Menu",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_menu_selector)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(sp);


    intent = new Intent().setClass(ac, Gallery.class);
    sp = tabHost.newTabSpec("gallery").setIndicator("Gallery",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_gallery_selector)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(sp);


    intent = new Intent().setClass(ac, Info.class);
    sp = tabHost.newTabSpec("info").setIndicator("Info",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_info_selector)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(sp);

    for(int i = 0; i < tabWidget.getChildCount(); i++){
        tabWidget.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_bar);
    }

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

    // Starting location listener service.
    ac.startService(new Intent(ac, LocationService.class));

    ac.setContentView(R.layout.tabbar_main);
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Copying files please wait...");
    super.onPreExecute();
}
```

Comment: onPostExecute() is called after the completion of doInBackground()

Comment: so what ? anything is wrong with that ?

Comment: i think you use separate threat for make tabActivity.

Comment: any code sample to support what you are saying ?

Comment: i think the better way is to make tabs in preExecute() and copy files in doInBackground()

Comment: it may be useful. But I have done it. I'm not sure how but instead of defining TabHost  and TabWidget in constructor, I did it in the onPostExecute and it worked !. Another i would like to ask if you have something about it, now I'm defining setContentView(R.layout.installation_screen) but I get an error, which says "Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'"  anyidea about it ?

Comment: bytheway I'm trying to do it to show my logo in the background beside progress bar which says something is loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way to do it, I have an image view which has visibility as GONE and In the onPreExecute() I'm setting the visibility of this image as VISIBLE. and Also onPostExecute() I'm making it GONE as like before.

Answer (score 0):

for tab 
layout your xml should b like this;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think its not about the layout. Because I have the same layout, but in the line that call setContentView(R.layout.installation_screen) I get that error. and I'm doing it onPreExecute(). if I remove it everything is fine. I just wanna show a background image instead of black screen while async task is runnig.